# Trying to run a lisp-dialect through inferior-lisp, but can't evaluate code

Tags: inferior-lisp

I'd like to run [txr lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-lisp.html) as an inferior-lisp process in Emacs.

From bash in xterm I can start a repl with `txr -i`.

[image: txr -i works from xterm]

I know I first need to change the `inferior-lisp-program` variable:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "txr -i")
```

Now I try to run it:

> M-x run-lisp

After I type the expression I want to evaluate I press the `enter` key and I see escape codes rather than the evaluation.

[image]

I also observe this behavior on a fresh instance of emacs started with `emacs -Q`.

From the txr man page:

> The interactive listener is based on 8 bit  character  processing. 
>   Its
>          editing functions do not recognize UTF-8 multi-byte characters.

I've tried changing the buffer coding system with `set-buffer-process-coding-system` to `raw-text` and `us-ascii` with no luck.

How might I debug/fix this?

Comment: Note that it is possible to run the REPL from `M-x ansi-term`.

Comment: Might Emacs be invoking`txr` with a pseudo-TTY as stdin? In that case, all that VT100 based editing kicks in. There isn't any command line switch to disable it. The `linenoise` function does an `isatty` check on the input descriptor, and that's that. If that's the source of trouble, can a command like `cat | txr -i` be used as an Emacs inferior-lisp? If stdin is piped through `cat`, that prevents `txr` from seeing a TTY; `cat` sees the TTY, `txr` sees a pipe. Another idea would be to hack up a REPL in TXR Lisp code, bypassing the Linenoise library entirely. That would also have UTF-8 input.

Comment: Rudimentary non-interactive REPL, with parse errors sent to standard output and exception catching: `txr -e '(whilet ((line (get-line))) (catch (prinl (eval (read line *stdout*))) (t (msg) (put-line \`** exception: @msg\`))))'`.

Comment: I couldn't get `cat | txr -i` to work in inferior lisp, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs invokes inferior processes with a pseudo-TTY device as standard input. TXR's listener `isatty` to decide whether the input is an interactive device; if so, then it goes into raw mode and provides editing, driving the terminal with ANSI/VT100 codes. It ignores the `TERM` environment variable's existence status or contents, or other such clues for whether to drive the terminal, or with what escape sequence language.

Starting in TXR 174, the existing `-n`/`--noninteractive` option's meaning has been extended: if the option is present, it causes the listener to treat the device as a non-TTY and operate in "plain" mode: line-buffered input with no prompts, no editing features and no generation of any ANSI/VT100 codes.

In addition, an important bugfix has been applied to make this plain mode actually work correctly. **Even if there is some trick in Emacs to run the inferior Lisp using just a pipe device, that bugfix is still required.**

The fixes were tested using `emacs` as to their efficacy in supporting the inferior Lisp operation.

The `-n` option can "clump" with `-i`, as in `txr -ni` or `txr -in`.

Comment: Excellent. I like this even better than a prompt-oriented REPL. Thanks!

Comment: In 175, there will be a `:prompt` command to print the current prompt (without incrementing the number), and a `:p` to just print the number without the `>`: like `*n` but not actually an expression. You need that info for accessing recently computed values by absolute number (modulo 100) like `*42`.